# php.ini not updating after changes

Tags: php

Followed a few tutorials but it just doesn't update.

- I restarted the server many times with sudo service apache2 restart and sudo apachectl restart
- I ran php --ini to check all the files being loaded
- I checked each file to see if it is being overwritten
- I made another override and checked if its being loaded
- Used the phpinfo() function to check if its being updated

I'm using PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21
Its a virtual machine in virtualbox

the change that I'm trying to make is for php to allow more inputs in a post.

I don't know if I should post here or in Super User

Comment: Which php.ini did you change? Because you have one for cli and one for apache

Comment: I changed the one that is showing on php --ini command. It s the cli one. I'll search for the apache one.

Comment: phpinfo() should show which ini file is being used.

Comment: it worked, thank you, didn't know about the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you are modifying the php.ini of the CLI instead of the one for apache. It should be under:

```
/etc/php/$VERSION/apache2/php.ini
```

Then restart apache.